# Alpine.JS how to save dynamic data after refresh

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I made a dropdown that after clicked, displays the result below. However, I cant seem to be able to figure out how to keep the data after refreshing. If I add ten different names, if I refresh the browser, I have to start over. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My HTML:

```
  <div x-data="addRemove()">
     <form x-on:submit.stop.prevent="addRemoveSubmit">
          <!-- The dropdown itself is a Larvel component -->
          <select x-model="newLast" id="last" 
               wire:model="Customer_Name">
               <option value="" selected>Assign Student</option>
                      @foreach($posts as $post)
                          <option  value="{{ $post->First_Name }} {{ 
                          $post->Last_Name }}" name="Customer_Name">
                              {{ $post->First_Name }} {{ $post- 
                           >Last_Name }}</option>
                          <br>     
                      @endforeach
          <button type="submit">Add Student</button>
                  <template x-for="(person, index) in 
                   Object.values(persons)" 
                  :key="index">
                      <tr>
                          <div><td x-text="person.last"></td>
                      </tr>
                  </template> 
     </form>
</div>
```

My javascript:

```
function addRemove() {
return { 
  newFirst: '', 
  newLast: '',
  // This makes page null after refresh 
  persons: '',
  addRemoveSubmit() {
    this.persons = [].concat({ 
      first: this.newFirst, 
      last: this.newLast
    }, this.persons);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario the simplest way is to use *Alpine.persist()* functionality, so in your object returned by *addRemove()*:

```js
return { 
  newFirst: '', 
  newLast: '',
  persons: Alpine.$persist([]).as("persons").using(sessionStorage),
  .....
```